# EF Eager load related entities from related entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm having difficulties with eagerly loading a complex relation type. Consider my entities:

```
public class User
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}

public class Ownership
{
    public User   Owner  { get; set; }
    public Device Device { get; set; }
}

public class Device
{
    public License License { get; set; }
}
```

Assume that all entities are in separate tables. I left out all the non-essential convention code. I can post more when needed.

My query:

```
var result = return context.Ownerships
              .Include(o => o.Device.License)
              .Where(o => o.Owner.UserName == userName)
              .Select(o => o.Device).ToList();
```

But this results in `null` valued licenses for all devices. However if I define the License like this:

```
public class Device
{
    public virtual License License { get; set; }
}
```

And query like this:

```
var result = return context.Ownerships
              .Where(o => o.Owner.UserName == userName)
              .Select(o => o.Device).ToList();
```

It works (License is not `null` for devices) but I rather not lazy load by default. The entities are served over rest so, by serialization, I get license info for each device that I query which is a lot of data over the line I don't need.

Any hints?

**Solution**

```
var result = return context.Ownerships
    .Where(o => o.Owner.UserName == userName)
    .Select(o => o.Device)
        .Include(d => d.License)
        .ToList();
```

Comment: `.Include(o => o.Device).Include(o => o.Device.License)`

Comment: Your first and second query ***should both work*** if lazy loading is enabled. But you said just the second query works (if lazy loading is enabled?) while the first query does not work (don't use lazy loading). It's not fair at all. Your `Device` class has nothing changed before and after the first query.

Comment: @Hopeless I guess they forgot to paste the `virtual` modifier in the second `Device` class.

Comment: @CodeCaster yes that makes sense, he disabled lazy-loading that way at first.

Comment: don't you need an ID property even though it is not on a lazy-loading?

Comment: @CodeCaster Wait; I **need** to make License virtual for it to work? So that means `include` to to be used on a virtual property with lazy loading disabled? That's not what I want though. I want to have 'License' non-virtual, so no lazy loading, but still be able to load it when required. How would I do that?

Comment: No, you need to make it virtual for lazy loading. Your post says _"However if I define the License like this"_, and proceeds to display the exact same definition as before. For `Include()` to work correctly, see my [first comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32761830/ef-eager-load-related-entities-from-related-entity?noredirect=1#comment53362749_32761830).

Comment: @CodeCaster argh, you are right, missed that one. Thanks though.

Comment: BTW @CodeCaster, adding the `.Include(o => o.Device).Include(o => o.Device.License)` doesn't help unfortunately...

Comment: Who downvoted this and why? If it's because of the `virtual` typo, please undo since I've fixed it. Otherwise give me some feedback I can work with.

Comment: @Aizen Yes you need Id properties with proper `nullable` settings on the `int`.  I left it out beacuse it clutters the example and doesn't add information (since it does work when making License virtual).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include only works on the projection of the thing you are doing it on.

In your case you are defining includes on `Ownership` but projecting `Device` which doesn't have any includes defined on it (eg `.Include(o => o.Device.License)` doesn't count).

You might be able to do this (but I haven't tested it):

```
return context.Ownerships
          .Where(o => o.Owner.UserName == userName)
          .Select(o => o.Device)
          .Include(d=>d.License)
          .ToList();
```

if not reverse the way you are querying eg:

```
return context.Devices
          .Include(d => d.License)
          .Where(d => d.Ownerships.Any(o=>o.Owner.UserName == userName))
          .ToList();
```

Comment: I could've sworn I tried the first example... I thought that didn't work and it's how I ended up at my question in the end... I think I was missing a `using` when I started.  Anyway, that did the trick, thanks man!